# Variables counting inside Loop

Tags: autohotkey

Few variables:

```
a, b, c    
x = 0
y = 100
z = 200
```

How to make first three of them counting with each cycle implementation? From **y** to **z** and back from **y** to **x** in second code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do here... Your code only shows a few variables with assignments and no Loop or attempt at Incremental Addition, which i believe is what you are trying to describe? Below is my interpretation of what you asked for:

```
x = 0
y = 100
z = 200

While (y <> x) {    
    If (A_Index < 100)
       y++
    else 
       y--
}
```

The code above will Add 1 to Y, which has a starting value of 100, until it reaches 200 than it will begin subtracting 1 from y until y = x which is 0...

Z was never used but you used it in your code so I left it.

Comment: Yes, it bit different from I asked for but useful.